# How to handle race conditions on a complex custom validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

People are making reservations using our Rails web app.

We get high traffic when reservations are made available, and sometimes two visitors get a valid reservation when there was only one left.

My validation is a bit complex, but here's a simplified version which gives an idea of part of what is being checked:

```
validate :time_availability

def time_availability
  if Reservation.where(date: date, arrival_time: arrival_time).count >= ReservationMax.for(date, arrival_time)
    errors.add(:arrival_time, "This time is not available")
  end
end
```

How would you make sure that two simultaneous requests don't both save when one of them saving should make the other invalid?

Comment: Have you looked at how other, similar, services work? Ticketmaster, for example, seems to hold your reservation for a period of time, after the process has been initiated, whether or not the transaction is completed. I suspect you would need to do something similar, in order to be certain not to overbook...

Comment: @BradWerth Definitely thought of that, but I don't like the UX in that case. Say there are 50 available and 90 people online trying to get them (fairly common for us). You have to convey to the 30 remaining that they are waiting for someone to timeout. It's a lot of "now", "wait", "now" "wait".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in a pretty interesting way which does not require any locking, rolling back, or extra transaction wrapping, but uses a unique index at the database level.

I added a column to the `Reservation` model called `seat_number` and added a unique index on `date`, `arrival_time`, and `seat_number`:

```
class AddSeatNumberToReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :reservations, :seat_number, :integer
    Reservation.update_all("seat_number=id") // so that existing reservations have a unique seat_number
    add_index :reservations, [:date, :arrival_time, :seat_number], unique: true
  end
end
```

Then I use an `around_save` to set the `seat_number` based on how many reservations already exist for that date and time, and rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and retry the save with a new seat number

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  around_save :check_for_race_condition

  def check_for_race_condition
    seat_count = Reservation.where(date: date, arrival_time: arrival_time).count
    begin
      self.seat_number = seat_count + 1
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      if seat_count + 1 >= ReservationMax.for(date, arrival_time)
        errors.add(:arrival_time, "This time is not available")
      else
        seat_count += 1
        retry
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It works beautifully.

In my multi-thread test, I set the db pool to 15, the reservation max (for a specific date and time) to 9, and run 14 simultaneous threads (apart from the main thread) trying to save a reservation for that date and time. The result is 9 reservations with seat_numbers 1 through 9, in order, and the remaining 5 gracefully return the reservation with the correct error.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure a model validation will work here due to the potential race condition - instead you need to wrap it in a transaction and do it backwards:

```
date, arrival_time = @reservation.date, @reservation.arrival_time
Reservation.transaction do
  @reservation.save!
  unless Reservation.where(date: date, arrival_time:arrival_time).count >= ReservationMax.for(date, arrival_time)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "This time is not available"
  end
end

if @reservation.persisted?
  redirect_to @reservation
else
  redirect_to :somewhere_else
end
```

This creates a pessimistic save and only commits the write if the "validation" succeeds. This removes the potential race condition between the validation being run and the actual insert being performed.

Comment: You should also attempt to perform the `Reservation.where(date: date, arrival_time:arrival_time).count >= ReservationMax.for(date, arrival_time)` check as a single DB query.

Comment: This looks like it does the trick, though I don't love adding all of that controller code. Also, there is a small cost to writing and rolling back, right? And does that really fix the race condition? Would perhaps two simultaneous requests possibly both roll back?

Comment: The cost should be roughly the same. The major difference here is that you minimize the risks of a record being created if the max is already hit since the validation is performed last. The two requests would have to hit the validation at the exact same ms which is not very likely

Comment: I'm going with my solution for now (I answered my own question) because it leaves no chance for a race condition and stays cleanly in the model (and at the database level). I might never have come up with my solution if I hadn't asked the question and thought about the different answers from the community, though! Thanks.

Comment: I tried testing your solution using multiple threads (to simulate simultaneous http requests) and unfortunately every thread completes a successful save and none of the transactions are rolling back. Is it possible that the validation is not fast enough?

Comment: I did try without the "validation" and the rollback does work.

Comment: Well, I solved it in a pretty interesting way I think. Would you mind checking out the accepted answer and letting me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate everything in a Transaction if you need to do more operations:

```
def create
  Reservation.transaction do
    reservation = Reservation.new(parsed_params)
    if reservation.save
      #do other things within the transaction
    else
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

Please read also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

and for optimistic locking:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of-label-Concurrency+and+integrity

your code should raise an StatementInvalid exception if you have an index.

Comment: I am aware of transactions, but as I understand it this does not lock the table, but makes sure that all saves in the transaction are rolled back if one if them fails. Not what I need in this case.

Comment: Do you have an index on the reservation id?

Comment: Yes, though not sure why they matters.

Comment: I see what you're getting at but uniqueness is not the issue. The issue is limiting the number of records with a certain date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested yet, but I have an idea. It came to me after commenting with coorasse on his answer about database indexes.

If there was another model for recording when a date and time were full, then `before_save`ing the `Reservation` I could create that record and the database would take care of uniqueness.

Migration for the new model and table:

```
class CreateFullReservationTimes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]                                                                   
  def change
    create_table :full_reservation_times do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.datetime :arrival_time

      t.index [:date, :arrival_time], unique: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Add `before_save` to the `Reservation` model:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :add_full_reservation_time, if: :arrival_time_will_be_full?

  def add_full_reservation_time
    begin
      FullReservationTime.create!(date: date, arrival_time: arrival_time)                                                         
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      errors.add(:arrival_time, "This time is not available")
      throw :abort
    end
  end

  def arrival_time_will_be_full?
    Reservation.one_or_none_left_at?(date, arrival_time)                                                                                     
  end
end
```

That way, if there's one (or no) reservations left `before save`ing, it tries to `create` a `FullReservationTime` (and if there's a race condition for two simultaneous "last reservations" only one will succeed due to `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUniqe`

---

UPDATE

I'm testing this using multiple threads to try to save multiple records at the same time.

If I start with one reservation left, the **test passes** and only one reservation is saved!

If I start with two reservations left, and run 3 simultaneous threads, **it fails** because they all save before there's time to check if there's one or none left.

I tried the method from max's answer (wrapping in a transaction, performing the validation after the save, and raising an `ActiveRecord::Rollback` if the validation fails, and the test did not pass. All threads successfully save the record...

Comment: So far all my tests on this are passing so I'm trying it in production. Seems good, and I'll see how it goes over the next few days as people reserve for this weekend.